# Converting Google Docs entire document area for true dark background usage

Tags: document, google-docs

I can see that I am able to change the background color for my Google Docs document through the page settings. If I choose a dark color such as black, I then notice that I have to manually adjust the text color to something light like white...but that still doesn't change the ticker to white (which shows me where my current typing position is located in the document).  The ticker is still black.

How do we change the ticker to white as well...?

Comment: I'm fairly certain after a ton of searching to say that you cannot do this with Google Doc's current "Page Setup" options or any of their other options that are provided. I'm looking for a solution to this as well and the best place I've found for possible solutions is the following URL (no luck finding anything so far though): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body

Answer (score -1):

I have made a whole [theme](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/Userscripts) for Google Docs and Google Translate through userscripts recently, so it's more pleasant for eyes mostly at night. No need to change page background or font color, therefore you can use the default settings and print it without modifying anything. :-)

[image]

[image]